# carto /cartocss : is there a function for "contains"?

Tags: carto, cartocss, string

I know how to set a specific color for a specific value (here `specific_string`) of a specific field (here `field1`)

```
#mydataset[field1="specific_string"] {
   marker-fill: #000000;
```

But what if I want to set this color for all the elements where field1 `CONTAINS` a specific string?

```
#mydataset[field1 ??CONTAINS?? "specific_string"] {
   marker-fill: #000000;
```

How do I write that please?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for using **regular expressions** on your filters, here's the official documentation of the [CartoCSS language](https://cartocss.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styling_concepts.html#filters) regarding filters.

Example from documentation:

```
/* a regular expression over name */
#world[name =~ "A.*"]
```

With the data you provided it's working as expected

[image]

I changed slightly the code to have a default marker fill value (`#fabada`). Then you can see how some dots are in blue as they contain the string `Diversité offre`.

```
#l {
   marker-fill: #fabada;
   marker-fill-opacity: 0.9;
   marker-line-color: #FFF;
   marker-line-width: 0.5;
   marker-line-opacity: 1;
   marker-placement: point;
   marker-type: ellipse;
   marker-width: [pertinence]*5;
   marker-allow-overlap: true;
}

#l[recurrence=~"Diversité offre"] {
   marker-fill: #A6CEE3;
}
```

There is an important caveat you need to take into account. Because you are having tags and looking for occurrences, the **last** rules will override any previous match. So if you have a point that matches more than one rule, only the last one will be rendered. To fix that you should work more in the SQL part to *unnest* your rows by tag, and then maybe use something like the [stacking chips hack](https://carto.com/blog/stacking-chips-a-map-hack/) to render the different values.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but it doesn't look to work for me. I have a column called "recurrence" in which I have TAGS separated by the "|" symbol (smal vertical bar). Please see here the link  of the .carto map : http://n.fonty.free.fr/divers/map(on%202018-03-06%20at%2017.31.16).carto

Comment: I've added more details to my answer based in your data

Comment: Thank you Jorge. If you look at the 3 pink points on the bottom left corner of your map, you will see that 2 of them are tagged "Diversité offre" and are still pink.

Comment: Please see image on this link to spot the 2 points : http://n.fonty.free.fr/divers/CN2AT.jpg

Comment: What is the problem with those 2 points? (in fact, I am seeing 3)

Comment: 2 of them are tagged "Diversité offre" and are still pink